# Open MyComputer using PHP COM class

Tags: php, com

i'm trying to open MyComputer using COM class ... whould you help me with the **name** of MyComputer in COM class ??
For example , if you wanna open NotePad you do this :

```
<?php
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->Run("notepad.exe");
$shell = null; ?>
```

Run("notepad.exe"); works for notepad , but when i use **Run("mycomputer.exe");** i face error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Unknown
> **Description:** Unknown' in E:\Localhost\root\test.php:3 Stack trace: #0 E:\Localhost\root\test.php(3): com->Run('computer.exe') #1 {main} thrown in E:\Localhost\root\test.php on line 3

i appreciate any help from you my dear friends <3

Comment: My Computer isn't a program and therefore you would be looking for Explorer.exe (Windows File Browser)

Comment: tnx buddy , it worked ... but it opens Libraries !! i want to open the main section of MyComputer where the drives are listed .

Comment: Not sure if you can pass in arguments but this might help you https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314853

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try :

```
<?php
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->Run("explorer.exe ,");
$shell = null; ?>
```

when we add "," it open My computer.